# how to extract speciific columns from a csv file and plot using python

Tags: python, csv, plot

I have a csv file that contains the following few lines of data:

```
# Vertex        X                Y                Z               K_I             K_II             K_III              J
  0       2.100000e+00      2.000000e+00     -1.000000e-04    0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00        0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    
  1       2.100000e+00      2.000000e+00      1.699733e-01    8.727065e+00  -8.696262e-04        -1.800691e-04   3.465355e-04    
  2       2.100000e+00      2.000000e+00      3.367067e-01    8.907810e+00  -2.548819e-04        -2.789738e-04   3.610383e-04
```

I would like to plot:

vertex (first column) versus K_I (5th column)

vertex (first column) versus K_II (6th column)

vertex (first column) versus K_III (7th column)

How do I extract the specific columns from this file and then plot a line graph from the columns?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To get you started you can look up the [CSV](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) library which is made to handle [CSVs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) (as well as tab and other delimited files.  There are a couple of options to plot the data, but [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent option you may want to look at.

And while not exactly what you want, one of my articles on [plotting from SQL Server using matplotlib and PyQT](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2664/plotting-sql-server-data-for-data-visualization/) was just published that includes some relevant examples of plotting in matplotlib with a PyQT Gui.  I don't address pulling the data from a CSV there, though.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/visualization.html) has built-in visualization support which makes this task very simple.  It is a lot more straight forward than csv + matplotlib since pandas abstracts that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col=0)
frame.K_I.plot() # Vertex is the x-axis
```

also "frame.plot()" plots all columns

Comment: I got an error message that says:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'K_I'